# View Transitioning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, view, transition

I'm new to Objective-C programming and I'm having a little trouble understanding how I transition between two views.

Basically, I have my main view (the view that loads up when the application opens) and I want to transition to a new view on pressing a button.  The user will **not** need to go back to the main view after pressing the button -- it's basically a title screen.

Could someone please briefly explain the steps I would need to take to make this happen?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of UIView's class method [transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW113). 
A call to switch from viewA to viewB could look like this:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:viewA 
                    toView:viewB 
                  duration:1.0 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft 
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    [viewA release];
                }];
```

As you mentioned the user won't get back to the mainView I added something to the completion parameter to get rid of viewA afterwards.

You can find the animation options [in the constants of the UIView class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW105) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't just want to copy & paste the code you should follow Apple's sample code step by step and remember you can download it:

[ViewTransitions sample application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/index.html)

> The ViewTransitions sample application demonstrates how to perform transitions between two views using built-in Core Animation transitions. By looking at the code, you'll see how to use a CATransition object to set up and control transitions.

Comment: @Jack Nutkins: Any news regarding your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to be a modal view, you can push on a new modal view controller which will then later be popped off when work is complete.  These are usually intended for small amounts of work

```
[container presentModalViewController:yourNavigationViewController animated:YES];
```

Otherwise you can modify the UIView stack using the two UIView transition class methods:

```
+ transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:
+ transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
```

For more info on these check out Apple's `UIView` class docs.